# Updating rows in PostgreSQL via Python - pandas.to_sql: update?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I know that [*insert or update if key exists* option](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14553) for `.to_sql()` hasn't been implemented yet, so I'm looking for an alternative.

---

The first thing that comes to mind is to use the `append` option:

```py
data.to_sql(
    "Dim_Objects",
    con=connection,
    if_exists="append",
    index=False
)
```

and remove duplicates in the database separately, after I inserted data:

```
DELETE FROM "Dim_Objects" a
      USING "Dim_Objects" b
      WHERE a."Code" = b."Code" 
        AND a."TimeStampUpdate" < b."TimeStampUpdate"
```

In this case, if there's a duplicate, I only keep the latest entry.

---

This approach seems to work but I hoped I could achieve the same using pandas directly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
     can you try? 
  
    data.to_sql('Dim_Objects', con=connection, if_exists='replace')
    
    sql = """
        UPDATE "different_table" AS f
        SET col1 = b.col1
        FROM your_table_name AS data
        WHERE a."Code" = b."Code"
    """
    
    with engine.begin() as conn:     
        conn.execute(sql)
```

Comment: `if_exists="replace"` would drop my whole table and replace it with the `data` dataframe, which is not what I want; I want to append new rows and replace where key already exists, but also I want to keep all records that are already in the table

Comment: sorry, You can try wirting the df in pandas as temp table in your db, then using sql create the matching columns. this code was for it. 
I updated some of the code. I typed the same db name by mistake